# getting an error invalid identifier s.site_id

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
WITH sdv_ar As(
          select * from  (
                SELECT
                    brv.subject_uid,
                    brv.record_id,
                    brv.log_id,
                    brv.audit_subcat,
                    brv.study_event_id,
                    brv.int_tec_fr_dt,
                    brv.subject_id AS subject_number,
                    brv.study_id 
                    || '-'
                    || brv.site_id AS tu_alias_cd,
                    CASE
                        WHEN ( MAX(CASE
                            WHEN brv.audit_subcat LIKE 'ENTERED%' THEN brv.log_id
                            ELSE 0
                        END) OVER(
                            PARTITION BY brv.record_id
                        ) = brv.log_id ) THEN TO_DATE(replace(item_value,' ','-') )
                        ELSE NULL
                    END AS visit_dt,
                    CASE
                        WHEN ( MAX(CASE
                            WHEN brv.audit_subcat LIKE 'ENTERED%' THEN brv.log_id
                            ELSE 0
                        END) OVER(
                            PARTITION BY brv.record_id
                        ) = brv.log_id ) THEN brv.int_tec_fr_dt
                        ELSE NULL
                    END AS entered_dt
                                                                                ,brv.FORM_ID 
                                                                                ,brv.SUBJECT_ID
                FROM
                    v_df_brv_log_std_site brv
                WHERE
                    form_id LIKE 'SV#_%' ESCAPE '#'
                    AND item_id LIKE 'SVSTDAT%'
                    AND VALIDATE_CONVERSION(replace(item_value,' ','-') AS DATE,'dd-mon-yyyy') = 1
                    AND record_id IN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                            record_id
                        FROM
                            v_df_brv_log_std_site
                        MINUS
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                            record_id
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                    record_id,
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN log_id = MAX(log_id) OVER(
                                            PARTITION BY record_id
                                        ) THEN audit_subcat
                                    END AS crf_status
                                FROM
                                    v_df_brv_log_std_site
                                WHERE
                                    ( audit_subcat LIKE 'INACTIVATED%'
                                      OR audit_subcat LIKE '%DELETED%'
                                      OR audit_subcat LIKE 'ACTIVATED%' )
                            )
                        WHERE
                            crf_status IS NOT NULL
                            AND ( crf_status LIKE '%DELETED%'
                                  OR crf_status LIKE 'INACTIVATED%' )
                    )
                ORDER BY
                    subject_uid,
                    study_event_id
            )
        WHERE
            entered_dt IS NOT NULL
            AND visit_dt IS NOT NULL
    ), sdv_base AS (
        SELECT
            
            trc.geo_reg1_nm                 AS region,
            trc.ropu_nm                     AS ropu,
            trc.ctry_nm                     AS country,
            trc.trc_alias_cd                AS study_country,
            trc.ctry_nm                     AS tr_ctry,
            tu.tu_alias_cd   AS study_site,
            tu.tu_status,
                                                s.record_id,
            s.entered_dt,
            s.visit_dt,
                                                s.subject_number
                                                --,
         
      
          FROM
            sdv_ar s 
            INNER JOIN da_cox.dm_ctm_tu tu ON ( s.study_id
                                                || '-'
                                                || s.site_id ) = tu.tu_alias_cd
                                              AND tu.curr_flg = 1
                                                          INNER JOIN dm_ctm_tu tu ON s.tu_alias_cd = tu.tu_alias_cd
                                       AND tu.curr_flg = 1

            INNER JOIN dm_ctm_trc trc ON trc.ctry_cd = tu.ctry_cd
                                         AND trc.tr_no = tu.tr_no
                                         AND trc.curr_flg = 1
                                        
--TEMPORAL_COMMENT_UNTIL_DATA--                                              INNER JOIN dm_ctm_tr tr ON tr.tr_no=trc.tr_no AND tr.curr_flg=1 AND tr.tr_stat < 4950 /* Excluding ended studies */
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT
        /*b."TR",
        b."REGION",
        b."ROPU",
        b."COUNTRY",
        b."STUDY_COUNTRY",
        b."TR_CTRY",
        b."STUDY_SITE",
        b."TU_STATUS",
        b."RECORD_ID",
        b."ENTERED_DT",
        b."VISIT_DT",
                                b."SUBJECT_NUMBER"*/
        *
                                
      
        
    FROM
         sdv_base b
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOs83.png)

Comment: well, `s`  in that position is an alias for `sdv_ar`, which does not contain a column named `site_id` ...

Comment: Please avoid to use images as code / output if it's not necessary.